# WebService PHP + PHONEGAP

Tags: php, web-service, apache-cordova

Ola não seui se aqui é o melhor lugar pra perguntar isso mas, tenho um banco mysql e pretendo criar uma aplicação com PHONEGAP pegando alguns dados desse banco ..
Alguem tem alguma dica de uma material onde eu possa começar aprender sobre isso ?
Obrigado.

Comment: Bem vindo o Stack Overflow, leia sobre as regras para postagem, sua pergunta deve ser específica, a sua está bastante ampla. Eu normalmente uso o site em arquitetura MVC, e um método isAjax para identificar se o a requisição vem do app e daí faço o restante. Como a pergunta é ampla não vou responder, mas você pode começar aprendendo MVC, sugiro o framework LazyPHP. Nl YouTube busque por "intel xdk php" que tem uns vídeos falando dessa integração.

Answer (score -1):

Você vai precisar de um webservice para consumir os dados do banco e retornar para seu app phonegap. Recomendo usar o Yii Frameework.

Espero ter ajudado, abraço.